# Question about meaning of "make" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "make" mean in this exchange?

> Burt: The car has been giving me trouble from the start
>
> Carlson: I’m really sorry for the inconvenience Mr. Andrews. Can you please confirm the **make** and model of the car?
>
> Burt: It’s a YWZA Sports.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking this up online? I'm sure you'll find many references, but nevertheless, here's something to get you started:

"**Make**" refers to the manufacturer of the car, like-Ford, Toyota, Honda, BMW, Fiat etc. "**Model**" refers to the particular style within each manufacturer's range of products. Therefore, in your example, Burt specifies the **make** as *YWZA* and **model** as *Sports*.

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_model), the use of "make" referring to manufacturer is especially seen in North America:

> Traditionally in North America, especially in police reports,
>   automobiles are specified by "year, make, model" – model year,
>   manufacturer and product, as in a "2000 Toyota Camry".

Also, take a look at this [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-marque-and-a-brand) from English Language & Usage.SE.